# texlive 2023 does not upgrage operating system :(EndeavourOS Linux x86_64)

Tags: texlive

following the instructions from  from https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html
i have give succesfully the  command cp-a 1013 2024
and the  directory /ur/local/texlive/2024 has been cretated

i have also download the   file `update-tlmgr-latest.sh`  in the `/ur/local/texlive/2024` directory
these are the files into the above directory

..  bin  doc.html  index.html  install-tl  install-tl.log  LICENSE.CTAN  LICENSE.TL  README  readme-html.dir  readme-txt.dir  README.usergroups  release-texlive.txt  texmf.cnf  texmfcnf.lua  texmf-config  texmf-dist  texmf-var  tlpkg  update-tlmgr-latest.sh

but when i run the  command

```
sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh -- --upgrade
```

with or wihout sudo  a I get the  following message

```
ncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%  
./runme.sh: updating in /usr/local/texlive/2024...
./runme.sh: tlmgr version says this is TeX Live 2023,
./runme.sh: and this updater script created: Tue Nov 21 02:13:39 CET 2023.
./runme.sh: have TL 2023, new version also 2023;
./runme.sh: using --upgrade doesn't make sense; terminating.
(./runme.sh: makeself creation date = Tue Nov 21 02:13:39 CET 2023.)
```

and nothing happens

how to upgrade texlive 2023 to 2224
thanks

Antonis

Comment: normally it's best to not "upgrade" but simply install texlive 2024 as new (you can always delete 2023 later if needed)

Comment: Did you re-boot? Your shell may be missing something in its PATH until you re-boot.